# PHP detectar caracteres no imprimibles ASCII

Tags: php, ascii

Estoy intentando detectar carácteres NO imprimibles en una cadena de texto recibida

Tengo el siguiente código con dos tipos de comprobación:

```
$cadenas = array('cadena1' => "asdf\n\r\t", 'cadena2' => 'ANGEL_CAMACHÃƒÂ³', 'cadena3' => 'LKA#@%.54');
foreach ($cadenas as $nombre => $caso_prueba) {
if (ctype_print($caso_prueba)) {
    echo "La cadena '$nombre' consiste completamente de caracteres imprimibles.";
} else {
    echo "La cadena '$nombre' no consiste completamente de caracteres imprimibles.";
}
echo "<br><br>";
if( preg_match('/[[:^print:]]/',  $caso_prueba))
    echo "La cadena '$nombre' . TIENE";
else
    echo "La cadena '$nombre' . NO TIENE";
echo "<br><br>";
        
}
```

Me devuelve esto:

```
La cadena 'cadena1' no consiste completamente de caracteres imprimibles.

La cadena 'cadena1' . TIENE

La cadena 'cadena2' consiste completamente de caracteres imprimibles.

La cadena 'cadena2' . NO TIENE

La cadena 'cadena3' consiste completamente de caracteres imprimibles.

La cadena 'cadena3' . NO TIENE
```

Cadena1 y Cadena2 deberían indicar que tienen caracteres NO Imprimibles y cadena3 deberia indicar que no tiene

Si este mismo código lo introduzco en la página de PhpTry de W3School (https://www.w3schools.com/php/phptryit.asp?filename=tryphp_intro) me devuelve esto:

```
La cadena 'cadena1' no consiste completamente de caracteres imprimibles.

La cadena 'cadena1' . TIENE

La cadena 'cadena2' no consiste completamente de caracteres imprimibles.

La cadena 'cadena2' . TIENE

La cadena 'cadena3' consiste completamente de caracteres imprimibles.

La cadena 'cadena3' . NO TIENE
```

Que es lo que estoy intentando conseguir.

Estoy con PHP 5.6

Alguna idea de porque no funciona correctamente en mi entorno?

Comment: No es un problema de versión de PHP. [Aquí puedes probar tu código en la versión 5.6](http://phptester.net), señalándolo en la parte superior. Debe ser un problema de caché o algo. Prueba a limpiar caché, a probar en modo incógnito del navegador o a renombrar el archivo `.php` o a llamarlo con un nuevo parámetro en el navegador: `tuarchivo.php?param=test`

Comment: ESe no es el problema, he hecho lo que dices y sale el mismo resultado. He probado en Firefox, Chrome y Edge saliendo en los tres el mismo resultado

Comment: Entonces será un problema de configuración en tu PHP. Revisa el archivo `php.ini` en busca de alguna pista, pero no modifiques nada sin saber lo que estás modificando. Por cierto, deberías considerar un cambio a PHP 7 al menos, a no ser que algo te obligue a seguir usando una versión ya obsoleta de PHP, cuyo suporte ha sido descontinuado hace ya casi 4 años: [*Support for PHP 5 has been discontinued since 10 Jan 2019.Please consider upgrading to 8.*](https://www.php.net/releases/index.php).

Comment: Poniendo un phpinfo() en esa página de w3schools veo que usan la versión `PHP Version => 7.1.1-1`.  Haz lo mismo y mira a ver que más diferencias hay con tu versión de PHP (quizás alguna libreria o vete a saber) e intenta que se parezca lo más posible a ese de w3schools para intentar conseguir saltarte el error.

Comment: No es problema de mi configuración, un amigo a usado el mismo código con el mismo resultado y versión de PHP que a mi

Comment: tiene que ver mas con apache que con php, hay plugins que traducen los caracteres no UTF8, cuando envias parametros por get no todos son admitidos